# Facebook Graph API blocking and reporting users

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm trying to build a content moderation in python and for this i wonder if it possible to block and report users. Within the Graph-API I wasn't able to find anything that indicates thats possible. Can this be somehow possible with a Post message?

I am currently using the facebook library and tinkering with the GraphAPI:

```
graph = facebook.GraphAPI(access_token=token, version = 2.8)
```

I'm really glad if anyone could guide me if blocking or reporting is possible within facebook the API. I also couldnt find anything anywhere else.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/blocked/

Comment: Thank you very much already, but also for reporting a user?

Comment: No, you can only block them for a specific page, but not report them.

Comment: knowing this helps a lot, thank you very much for responding to my otherwise idle post!